# how to iterate over a list with condition

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, if-statement

I know this question might be a bit inappropriate for this platform but I have nowhere else to ask for help.

I'm new to python and I'm trying to learn how to iterate over a list with some conditions. I have the next problem - for each unique link from Where to Where, I want to choose one of the most profitable suppliers. A profitable supplier is a supplier that most of the days of the week turned out to be cheaper (that is, had a lower cost) than other suppliers. The dataset is the following where columns are: 1st-From, 2nd-To, 3rd-Day in a week, 4th-supplier's number, 5th-Cost.

[image]

To solve this task, I've decided firstly to create a new column and list with unique routes.

```
df_routes['route'] = df_routes['From'] + '-' + df_routes['Where']
routes = df_routes['route'].unique()
len(routes)
```

And then iterate over it but I do not fully understand how the structure should look like. My guess is that it should be something like this:

```
for i, route in enumerate(routes):
    x = df_routes[df_routes['route'] == route]
    if x['supplier'].nunique() == 1:
        print(route, supplier)
    else:
...
```

I don't know how to structure it further and whether this is the right structure. So how it should look like?

I will really appreciate any help (tips, hints, snippets of code) on this question.

Comment: We will really appreciate to have a sample as plain text data :)

Comment: **DO NOT** post images of code, links to code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question.  Also, we don't need the entirety of the data , just a reasonable sample

Comment: @itproph66 oh okay, thank you, I still do not fully understand what is acceptable to do here and what is not. I will delete my link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more efficiently solved with pandas functions rather than looping

Let `df` be a portion of your dataframe for the first two routes. First we sort by cost and group by the route and the 'Day'. This will tell us for each day and each route which supplier is the cheapest:

```
df1 = df.sort_values('Cost', ascending = True).groupby(['From','To', 'Day']).first()
```

`df1` looks like this:

```
            Supplier    Cost
From To Day     
BGW MOW 1   3   75910
        2   3   75990
        3   3   27340
        4   3   75990
        5   11  19880
        6   3   75440
        7   11  24740
OSS UUS 1   47  65650
        2   47  47365
        3   47  70635
        4   47  47365
        5   47  62030
        6   47  62030
        7   47  71010
```

Next we count the number of mentions for each supplier for each route:

```
df2 = df1.groupby(['From','To'])['Supplier'].value_counts().rename('days').reset_index(level=2)
```

`df2` looks like this:

```
        Supplier    days
From To     
BGW MOW 3           5
    MOW 11          2
OSS UUS 47          7
```

eg for the first route, supplier 3 was the cheapest for 5 days and supplier 11 for 2 days

Now we just pick the first (most-mentioned) supplier for each route:

```
df3 = df2.groupby(['From','To']).first()
```

`df3` is the final output and looks like this:

```
        Supplier    days
From To     
BGW MOW 3           5
OSS UUS 47          7
```

Answer (score 0):

**Groupby** dataframe based on columns *(['From','To', 'Day'])* and use aggregate **min** *('Cost')*

function to get result

```
df.groupby(['From','To', 'Day']).min('Cost').reset_index()
```